# Java Reflection, getMethod()

Tags: java, class, reflection, methods

I'm working with the basics of Java reflection and observing information on methods of classes.  I need to get a method that matches specifications as described by the getMethod() function.  However, when I do this I get a NoSuchMethodException, and I was hoping you could tell me why my implementation is incorrect.

```
static void methodInfo2(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException, 

NoSuchMethodException{

        Class cls = null;
        try{
            cls = Class.forName(className);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Cls:  "+cls);


        Method method1 = cls.getMethod("test", null);
        System.out.println("method1:  "+method1);


    }
```

EDIT1:When I print out "Cls:  "+cls, the output is "Cls:  class a8.myclass2".  Why does it append the class part?  (the a8 is correct, so don't worry about that) /EDIT1

This is the function I use to read in a class from my main function, and then I want to getMethod() with the parameters "test" and null, where "test" is the name of the method and null means the method has no parameters.  The class I am reading in is called myclass2 which is here:

```
package a8;

public class myclass2 {

    void test(){
        //"takes no parameters"
        //"returns bool"
        //"name starts with test"
        //return true;
    }

}
```

As you can see, the method does infact exist in the class.  If you could point out my mistake, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your test method public.  I believe Class.getMethod() is limited to public methods.

Comment: It does, and you beat me to it. +1 From the JavaDoc for `getMethod()`: "Returns a Method object that reflects the specified **public** member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object."

Answer (score 3):

Without you posting the exact exception and your output, its hard to tell, but I suspect it is because the classes are in two separate packages, and since the default modifiers for a method are just `protected` it fails.

Use `getDeclaredMethod()` to get a method that isn't normally visible.

Comment: Nope, they were within the same package.  The answer above worked though.

Comment: Might default to private then. Either way, if you use `getDeclaredMethod()` you **can access anything**.